# Fat Free Framework dynamic cache expiration

Tags: php, caching, fat-free-framework

I am trying to improve my Fat Free Framework web app by using cached queries, wherever possibile.

I am wondering whether it would make any sense to try caching even queries involving data which changes quite ofter or so, by applying a little 'trick'.

IE, tipically you wouldn't cache this:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE status = 'open';
```

But what if I could instead cache it indefinitely and have external factors clear its cache when a specific event (e.g. a task is closed, in this case) occurs?

If this is my query:

```
$tasks = $this->db->exec(
    array(
        "SELECT *
         FROM tasks
         WHERE status = 'open'"
    ),
    NULL,
    86400
);
```

is there any possible way by which I can force its 24h-long cached version to expire earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

**Solution #1:**

Clear the whole cache content: `$f3->clear('CACHE')`

**Solution #2:**

Tag your cached query:

```
$tasks = $this->db->exec(
  array(
    "SELECT *
     FROM tasks
     WHERE status = 'open'"
  ),
  NULL,
  [86400,'mytag'] // << tag defined here
);
```

Then you can clear only the cache content matching this tag:

```
Cache::instance()->reset('mytag');
```

Comment: Very nice, I had no idea I could tag queries this way. Thanks.